# Create a Slack channel from Salesforce flow

Tags: visual-workflow, slack, slack-salesforce-app

I am trying to use the new Salesforce flow action to create a Slack channel, in my Summer '22 sandbox.
The action requires inputting a Slack app id and a Slack workspace id.
When I enter these and run the flow, I get an error.
I know my Salesforce and Slack are connected because when I search for a specific Salesforce Account on Slack, it finds it.

What am I missing?

Did anyone see an example where this new feature is working?
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Is your slack user in the workspace? Has the slack user already authorized that app?

Comment: Yes, I have a single user, me. I created a new workspace and reinstalled the app

Comment: How did you connect salesforce and slack?

Comment: @AlbaRivas I enabled Sales Cloud for Slack on Salesforce and tried to install Sales Cloud for Slack on Slack, but I noticed that even though the installation completed successfully, the app is not present on the Slack menu and I cannot figure out why

Comment: Once you install it in slack you have to connect it to Salesforce by login in with your Salesforce user. Try reinstalling the app on slack and going through that process

Comment: @AlbaRivas only when Production was upgraded to Summer '22 I was able to connect. To the sandbox (which is what I am trying to work with) I still cannot connect because the login link does not let me change the URL from the production URL to the Sandbox URL

Comment: I am glad that you solved the issue in production. Try to refresh your sandbox just in case, or submit a case